# google app script won't running multiple function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I write a script and it works fine if you run them separately from app script (RUN bottom). If I run it combined with the "run" bottom in app script it is working, when a enable the checkbox in the sheet, it is not working at all, *clearall()* is always working, *addrecord()* is working if I put it before var *checkexist = ...* , the other 2 are not working (running).

What is wrong here?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("KLANTinput");
  var checkadd = sheet.getRange("AI3").getValue();
  if (checkadd === 1) {
    var checkexist = sheet.getRange("X2").getValue();
    if (checkexist === 0) {
      addContactPhoneAndCreateFolder();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
      createNewFolderInGoogleDrive();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
    addrecord();
    Utilities.sleep(500);
    clearall();
    var checkstate = sheet.getRange("AH3");
    checkstate.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}

function addContactPhoneAndCreateFolder() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("KLANTinput");
  var first_name = sheet.getRange("J5").getValue();
  var last_name = sheet.getRange("AD5").getValue();
  var email = sheet.getRange("J15").getValue();
  var adres = sheet.getRange("J7").getValue().concat(" ").concat(sheet.getRange("Z7").getValue()).concat(" ").concat(sheet.getRange("J9").getValue()).concat(" ").concat(sheet.getRange("AD9").getValue());
  var phone = sheet.getRange("J13").getValue();
  Logger.log(adres);

  var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(first_name, last_name, email);
  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");

  group.addContact(ContactsApp.createContact(first_name, last_name, email));

  var contact = ContactsApp.findByEmailAddress(email);
  contact.setHomeAddress(adres);
  contact.setPrimaryEmail(email);
  //contact.setWorkAddress(adres);
  contact.setHomePhone(phone);
}

function createNewFolderInGoogleDrive() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("KLANTinput");
  var folderName = sheet.getRange("J5").getValue().concat(" ").concat(sheet.getRange("AD5").getValue()).concat(" ").concat(sheet.getRange("J9").getValue()).concat(" ").concat(sheet.getRange("AD9").getValue()).concat(" ").concat(sheet.getRange("AD19").getValue());
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("sheetID");
  //Logger.log(folderName);
  var nfolder = folder.createFolder(folderName);

}

function addrecord() {

  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sss.getSheetByName("KLANTinput");
  var datasheet = sss.getSheetByName("KLANTpredb");

  var values = [[sheet.getRange("C2").getValue(),     //DATE + TIME
  sheet.getRange("J3").getValue(),     //DATE
  sheet.getRange("K2").getValue(),     //DD
  sheet.getRange("N2").getValue(),     //MM
  sheet.getRange("Q2").getValue(),     //YY
....

  Logger.log(values)



  //var roow = datasheet.getLastRow()
  //Logger.log(roow)
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 45).setValues(values);

}
```

Comment: Did you read the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73065159/google-app-script-runs-with-the-testbottom-not-with-the-checkbox)? Do note that  there's a [established procedure to dispute a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-already-has-answers-here-but-it-does-not-what-can-i-do-when-i). Don't delete and if you do ask a new question, don't copy paste the exact same question, clearly explain why you think it's not a duplicate.

Comment: tl;dr because your script is calling services that requires permissions, ContactsApp, DriveApp , instead of using a simple trigger, use an installable trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your awnsers; Google Sheets OnEdit() - You do not have permission to call a service. Did the job for me.